# Adjektive im Sachverzeichnis

Tags: adjective

In einem Buch, das später an den Springer-Verlag geht, baue ich ein Sachverzeichnis auf. Ich stehe vor der Frage, ob darin Adjektive als Untereinträge dekliniert werden. Zum Beispiel:

```
Adjektiv
  gebeugtes 123
  dekliniertes 456
```

oder

```
Adjektiv
  gebeugt 123
  dekliniert 456
```

(Im Sachverzeichnis ist "Adjektiv" der Haupteintrag und "gebeugt(es)" bzw. "dekliniert(es)" Untereinträge. Auf Seite 123 bzw. 456. des Buches redet man von gebeugten bzw. deklinierten Adjektiven.)

Gibt es irgendwelche allgemeine Empfehlungen, Richtlinien oder Regeln diesbezüglich? Das offizielle Regelwerk von Springer schweigt sich dazu bis auf die Angabe "Nominativ Singular" aus (und direktes Nachfragen ist in meinem Fall nicht drin).

Answer (score 3):

In deinem Verzeichnis ist das Adjektiv nicht vorangestellt, sondern nachgestellt. Es kann daher kein Attribut des Substantivs sein, und daher darf es meiner Auffassung nach auch nicht gebeugt werden.

Dass Substantiv und Adjektiv auf verschiedenen Zeilen stehen, halte ich für irrelevant. Wichtig ist, in welcher Reihenfolge die Wörter gelesen werden.

Diese beiden Varianten halte ich für korrekt:

1. > gebeugtes Adjektiv 123
   >   dekliniertes Adjektiv 456
2. > Adjektiv, gebeugt 123
   >   Adjektiv, dekliniert 456

Will man nun ein Verzeichnis haben, bei dem das Substantiv zuerst genannt wird, kann man nur von Variante 2 ausgehen und erhält somit dann diese Auflistung:

> - Adjektiv
>
>   - gebeugt 123
>   - dekliniert 456

Answer (score 3):

Der angehängte Bildschirmauszug stammt aus dem Index des ["Leitfadens für Lektoren"](https://www.vfll.de/leitfaden/) des "Vereins der freien Lektoren und Lektorinnen", einem Dokument, das sich u.A. intensiv mit der Erstellung von Schlagwortregistern auseinandersetzt (Ich nehme an, die sollten sowas wissen)

[image]

Gleich der zweite Eintrag enthält ein Adjektiv in deklinierter Form.

Darüberhinaus gibt es eine DIN-Norm (wen wundert's), die sich mit der Erstellung von Schlagwortregistern beschäftigt. DIN 31630, die leider nicht frei zugänglich ist ("Begriffe, Formale Gestaltung von gedruckten Registern") sollte Auskunft geben können.

Comment: @tofro: Nehmen wir mal an, das Substantiv stünde hier nicht im Plural sondern im Singular. Was würde dann in der Liste stehe? a) *»Abschlussarbeit, studentisch«* oder b) *»Abschlussarbeit, studentische«* Genau darum dreht sich die Frage von user49915, aber dein Posting liefert leider keine Antwort auf diese Frage. Denn im Plural muss sowohl bei a) als auch bei b) *»studentische«* stehen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich denke, es ist relativ egal, woher die Beugung des Adjektives kommt (ob vom Numerus oder woanders her). Sie ist auf jeden Fall drin und es steht **nicht** da: "Abschlussarbeiten, studentisch". Ich würde ja gerne wissen, was da in der DIN-Norm steht, aber die Antwort auf diese Frage ist mir zu teuer...

Answer (score 0):

Wenn ich mich nicht irre, hat Springer bereits ein Buch veröffentlicht. Oder vielleicht schon zwei? :-))

Guck' doch einfach in Publikationen der – sagen wir – letzten fünf Jahre, dann weißt du, wie das bei Springer gehandhabt wird. Im Übrigen ist es logischer, *Adjektiv, gebeugtes* zu schreiben statt *Adjektiv, gebeugt*, denn Ersteres ist ja die Auflösung von *gebeugtes Adjektiv*, nicht von * *gebeugt Adjektiv*.

Comment: Ach, user49915, du musst Dinge auseinanderhalten, die nicht identisch sind. Adjektive in Postposition werden in der Tat nicht flektiert. Folglich, beispielsweise: *Cola light, Henkel trocken, Hänschen klein, Röslein rot* [Goethe]. Die Frage der Auflösung stellt sich hier erst gar nicht, ergo auch nicht die nach Übernahme oder Tilgung der Flektion. Das ist das eine.

Comment: Das andere: Dass "man nicht" *Benzin bleifreies* oder *Cola lightes* sagt, liegt daran, dass Adjektive in Postposition ... s.o. *bleifreies Benzin* ist komplett regelkonform (Flektion entsprechend Genus, Numerus & Kasus). *Lightes Cola* komt in der Tat nicht vor, weil *light* gegenwärtig nicht flektiert wird, während *cool* durchaus flektiert wird, z.B. in *eine coole Band*. Tja, Sprache ist arbiträr und konventionell, na, du weißt schon.